# view not updating in angularjs after a promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, scope, factory

I have a factory which fetches data from server and passes to controllers , many controllers are calling get methods from the factory , but only the scope variable of controller that calls the factory first is changed in view not all... here is my factory code

```
(function () {
angular.module('myapp').factory('agendaFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var user = "";
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var agenda = {
        getAll: function (tempData, addType) {
            $http.post('/api/' + addType + '/getAll', tempData).success(function (data, status) {
                console.log(addType, data);
                //console.log(status);
                defer.resolve(data);

            }).error(function (err, status) {
                console.log(err, status);
                defer.reject(status);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
    return agenda;
}]);
}());
```

here are the two controllers calling them..

```
changeData = function (data) {
            console.log("called function in liffe");
            $scope.lifetimeData = data;
        }
        agendaFactory.getAll(tempData, addType).then(function (data) {
                console.log('lifeData', data);
                changeData(data);
                return;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('today err', err);
            })
```

and second controller

```
changeData = function (data) {
                console.log("called function in year");
                $scope.yearData = data;
            }
            agendaFactory.getAll(tempData, addType).then(function (data) {
                console.log('yeardata', data);
                changeData(data);
                return;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('today err', err);
            });
```

but data from only first controller is being updated in the view

Comment: `$http` functions already return a promise, no need to wrap them in a promise. Also `sucess` and `error` are deprecated, just use `then`. And lastly, could you provide a plunkr/fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @NexusDuck this is a snippet from a large app , reproducing it would be very difficult , as you suggested i should just use $http promises so can you please write an answer so that I can try it out , THanks

Comment: It won't help solve your issue, just get rid of the deprecated stuff. See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) for more info. Also, you should be able to just reproduce a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no need to reproduce the whole app

Comment: Thanks , got rid of $q and success, error , now its working like charm :)

Comment: Okay that's odd, I'll post an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the promise wrapper since `$http` already returns a promise. Also get rid of the success/error handlers since they're deprecated.

```
(function () {
angular.module('myapp').factory('agendaFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var user = "";
    var agenda = {
        getAll: function (tempData, addType) {
            return $http.post('/api/' + addType + '/getAll', tempData);
        }
    };
    return agenda;
}]);
}());
```

You can then handle the success/error conditions in your controller